# WP-CLI mysteriously stopping while downloading the core

Tags: wp-cli

I'm jazzed about WP-CLI but for some reason when I run `wp core download` it says `Downloading WordPress 4.4.1 (en_US)...` and pauses for 20 seconds or so and then just goes back to the terminal prompt. No error or anything. I check the contents of the folder and there's nothing in it. Have tried multiple times.

I have already changed the path for PHP to be MAMP's version of php (I use MAMP) and WP-CLI seems to work fine on already installed instances. I'm wondering if this is a terminal issue. I have noticed something similar when uploading files via sftp.

Answer (score 1):

Well, nine months later I revisited the issue and it turns out my local version of php was out of date thanks to my version of MAMP being an older copy. Updated MAMP, and therefore my working PHP version, and all works splendidly now!